# MPAndroidChart ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in CircleBuffer

Tags: android, arrays, geometry, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChartLibrary to show a chart in my app, all is going well but some users in some devices are getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the library:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:306)
   at com.github.mikephil.charting.buffer.CircleBuffer.feed(CircleBuffer.java:26)
   at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawCircles(LineChartRenderer.java:492)
   at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawExtras(LineChartRenderer.java:458)
   at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:236)
```

Here is the full error: http://crashes.to/s/c13bf588bf4

My app chart has the DrawCircles enabled so I think this is related, anyone know what is happening and how to solve it?
Thank you very much

Comment: Error says someone tried to access an array of length 0 with an index of -1. I'm betting you are somehow passing in invalid values to a library call. Without code to see how you're feeding the library, I can't speculate any further.

Comment: Thank you for answering iheanyi you gave me the clue. I was using a combined Line Chart with two ArrayList as data source and one of the "add" call was in the wrong place so when the value to add was 0 it wasn't adding it to the ArrayList, ending with two ArrayList of different sizes.